# Write file to HDFS from (non-cluster) local machine

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, java

I am trying to find some tips to solve my problem. But I really have no idea how to do it.

I have a HADOOP HDFS and I need to write data from my local machine to HDFS using Java. Currently, I've solved it in this way:

1. Create file on my local machine
2. Create SSH connection to cluster where Hadoop is installed
3. Copy file to cluster(local OS)
4. Copy file from local cluster OS to HDFS(`hadoop fs -put`).

It works fine but now I need to copy files without SSH. I mean, I need to do in this way:

1. Create file on my local machine(not in Cluster)
2. Copy file directly to HDFS

All examples what can I could find show how to copy files from local OS (cluster) to HDFS. Has anyone solved a problem like this?

I write code like this:

```
    System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "jaas.conf");
    System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "krb5.conf");   


    UsernamePasswordHandler passHandler = new UsernamePasswordHandler("user", "pass");

    LoginContext loginContextHadoop = new LoginContext("Client", passHandler);
    loginContextHadoop.login();     


    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos");
    org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(configuration);
    org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(loginContextHadoop.getSubject());

    FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://URI:50020"), configuration);


    System.out.println(hdfs.getUsed());
```

And getting error like this:
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcNoSuchProtocolException): Unknown protocol: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol

I think i use wrong port, i get it from dfs.datanode.ipc.address. Does anybody has any ideas?

Comment: install hdfs client on your local machine and use it in the same way (hdfs dfs -put)

Comment: I use org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem to connect and getting error: Connection refused. I do it in this way:
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.set("password", pass);
FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI(<MY URI>), configuration, user);

What am i do wrong?

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: default port for namenode ipc is 8020, try it

Comment: @fi11er i find 50020 from my hadoop administrator, and when i use 8020 i get an error "Connection refused"

Comment: 50020 is a default port of datanode, when you creating URI object, you should connect to namenode. check your network access (you can use telnet for this).

Comment: Thak you, for namenode all works fine